# How to use Threading correctly in pyqt?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qthread, worker

I am very new to this PyQt, so please I need some help. I created a `MainWindow` which is imported from another file. `collect_host_status` also imported from another py file. Basicly the GUI works, but freezing obviously, so therefore I need to use threading for long running process. So far I have changed my code to be like this, but when I click on the button which suppose to check the hosts, happens nothing. :( I dont really get it how to connect the textEdit from MainWindow class to Worker class. As how it is now, it seems like Worker class has no clue what is really `self.ui.textEdit`.

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal()
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
             
        
    def run(self):
        hostname = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        output_text = collect_host_status(hostname)
        for i in output_text:
            if "not found" in i:
                w = i.replace(" not found", "")
                self.ui.textEdit_3.append(w)
            else:
                self.ui.textEdit_2.append(i)
        self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
                 
                
        self.ui.exitbutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.actionExit_2.triggered.connect(self.close)
                
        self.ui.actionOpen_2.triggered.connect(self.openfiles)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit.clear)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit_2.clear)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit_3.clear)
        
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit_2.clear)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit_3.clear)
              
        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton_2, SIGNAL("clicked()",), self.buttonclicked)

      
        
    def buttonclicked(self):
        
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)


        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread. If you need to commnunicate between threads, use [custom signals](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt, as with most UI frameworks, does not allow any kind of access to objects from outside its main thread, which means that external threads cannot create widgets, reading properties (like `toPlainText()`) is unreliable and writing (such as using `append()`) might even lead to crash.

Even assuming that that was possible, as you pointed out the worker has no clue about `self.ui.textEdit` and other objects, and that's pretty obvious: `self.ui` is an attribute created on the main window instance, the thread has no `ui` object. I suggest you to do some research about how classes and instances work, and how their attributes are accessible.

The only safe and correct way to do so is to use custom signals that are emitted from the thread and connected to the slots (functions) that will actually manipulate the UI.

In the following code I made some adjustments to make it working:

- the worker thread directly subclasses from QThread;
- only one worker thread is created, and it uses a Queue to get requests from the main thread;
- two specialized signals are used to notify whether the request is valid or not, and directly connected to the `append()` function of the QTextEdits;
- I removed the `finished` signal, which is unnecessary since the thread is going to be reused (and, in any case, QThread already provides such a signal);
- changed the "old style" `self.connect` as it's considered obsolete and will not be supported in newer versions of Qt;

```py
class Worker(QThread):
    found = Signal(str)
    notFound = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            hostname = self.queue.get()
            output_text = collect_host_status(hostname)
            for i in output_text:
                if "not found" in i:
                    self.notFound.emit(i.replace(" not found", ""))
                else:
                    self.found.emit(i)

    def lookUp(self, hostname):
        self.queue.put(hostname)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.buttonclicked)

        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.found.connect(self.ui.textEdit_2.append)
        self.thread.notFound.connect(self.ui.textEdit_3.append)
        self.thread.start()

    def buttonclicked(self):
        if self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText():
            self.thread.lookUp(self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Just one question, if I want to quit now from the application, after I checked several hosts, it says : "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running". And then it is crashing.

Comment: The problem is that the thread has to be stopped "gracefully", and there are many ways to do so: for instance, you could put an integer to the queue, and add a check (eg. `if isinstance(hostname, int):`) that could then exit the while with a `break`, and you also need to use `self.thread.wait()` in the function that would actually quit/close, so that the program can safely close after the thread has finished.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! That works perfectly, but the main thing is that I want it to be unlimited. I dont  know how many hosts I will check at the same time, can be 10 or 60. So integer solution is not the best.

Comment: @Oborzil sorry but I don't understand your comment. Using an integer is just a possible way to do it: since you're using strings, checking if the returned value from the `queue.get()` is an integer is a safe way to assume it's not a hostname and it should be dealt with in another way (a `break`, in your case, which will cause the while loop to exit and the `run()` to finish. When you want to quit, just put the integer in the queue, and wait for the thread to complete.

Comment: Ok! Thanks @musicamante! I have tried serveral ways, but I could not get it to work :(.
I appreciate your help and effort.

Comment: I don't understand what could be the problem, it seems pretty simple to me, otherwise there's something you're implying and that you didn't explain. If you still can't get it, create a new question.